# Getting data from FutureBuild snapshot without returning a widget (flutter_web3_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart, ethereum, metamask

I'm using a lib called flutter_web3_provider to communicate with eth wallets and make transactions in the blokchain, but I'm struggling to get data without using FutureBuilder, because this:

`promiseToFuture(webClient.getBalance(ethereum.selectedAddress))`

returns me a `NativeJavaScriptObject`

but if I use a `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: balanceFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text("Balance " + snapshot.data.toString());
            },
          ),
```

I can get the balance of this ETH wallet

But this way I'm forced to always return a widget, instead of just setting a new state.

Does anyone know an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: You can use StatefulWidget and call balanceFuture when you need it. for example : inside of initState or onTap function

Comment: Yes but I do, I only get a value in NativeJavaScriptObject, and I cannot do anything with this object. But if I get as a snapshot like that everything goes smoothly

Comment: I found a solution using promiseToFutureAsMap instead of promiseToFuture